# Как отличить понятия ключ, параметр и опция в cmd?

Tags: cmd

Как отличить понятия ключ, параметр и опция в командной строке?

Comment: Зависит от контекста.

Comment: Никак, это синонимы.

Answer (score 1):

Различие чисто функциональное. Технически,- как  уже было отмечено, - это одно и то же.

**Параметр** - это взгляд изнутри утилиты (или скрипта) вызываемой командной строкой. То есть это то, что является *частью командной строки* и может быть использовано утилитой. Так сказать, взгляд программиста на входные данные программе.

**Ключ** - это директива утилите, указывающая по какой подпрограмме действовать, какой функционал использовать. Это взгляд со стороны пользователя утилиты.

**Опция** - тоже что и **ключ**, но принципиальное значение тут имеет то, что опция подразумевает *многовариантность*. Т.е. опция может быть указана, а может и нет, и имеет место быть их множество. Это тоже взгляд со стороны пользователя.

И, наконец, ещё раз о **параметре**. С точки зрения пользователя - это есть *значение* для опции(ключа). Т.е. утилита может работать совместно с опцией указывающей по какой подпрограмме работать, где входными данными будут служить значения параметра ключа.

Comment: Неизвестно, о чем именно думал автор вопроса, но imho наиболее полезным был бы пересказ [вот этого текста](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html#Argument-Syntax) своими словами (особенно, если допустить, что `параметр` в вопросе соответствует `argument` в тексте от GNU)